# How to split pdf file by one page and remove unused objects (optimize)

Tags: java, itext7

I need to split large documents (several thousands of pages and 1-2 Gb) using **itext 7**

I already tried to split pdf using this reference 
https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/splitting-pdf-file
and also doing something like this:

```
try (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(outputPdfPath.toString()))) {
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(destFolder));

        int numberOfPages = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
        int pageNumber = 0;

        while (pageNumber < numberOfPages) {
            try (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(
                    new PdfWriter(destFolder + pages.get(pageNumber++).id + ".pdf"))) {
                pdfDoc.copyPagesTo(pageNumber, pageNumber, document);
            }
        }
        log.info("Provided PDF has been split into multiple.");
    }
```

Both examples works perfectly fine but created documents are large and with lots of unused fonts, images, objects.
How can I remove all this unused objects to make newly created one paged pdfs weigh less.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the document?

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk
Here you can find file I was playing with - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1undfzVqy5usOL-fMj5h-vPo0sD3mkoMP
It is documentation of FineReader

Comment: Also I tried this thing to remove unused fonts from page, but after that encodings were messed up.
https://itextpdf.com/ru/resources/examples/itext-7/unembed-font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your document is as follows: each page shares a lot of (maybe even all)the fonts/xobjets of the document. While coping pages, iText doesn't know whether the resources are needed on the page or not: it just copies themm and that's why you get so huge resultant pdfs.

The option you are looking for is iText's `pdfSweep`.

It's general purpose is redaction of some page's content, however besides that `pdfSweep` also optimizes the pages while redacting.

So how to sovle yout problem?

a) Specify the redaction area as a degenerate rectangle

b) Clean up the pages (of splitted documents or of the original document):

```
    PdfCleanUpLocation dummyLocation = new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), null);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(input), new PdfWriter(output));

    PdfCleanUpTool cleaner = (cleanUpLocations == null)
            ? new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfDocument, true)
            : new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfDocument, cleanUpLocations);
    cleaner.cleanUp();

    pdfDocument.close();
```

I've tried this approach to process the first of your resultant documents (which represents the first page).

The size of the document *before* `pdfSweep` processing: 9282 KB.

The size of the document *after* `pdfSweep` processing: 549 KB.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me a lot. Marking as correct answer.

Comment: Hello again, @UladzimirAsipchuk, your advice worked well, but I still have errors while cleaning some pages of this document - "No glyphs defined for type3 font" exception was throwing. I would appreciate any help.